# Why does DataBinding on WinForms not work on one of my forms but on the others?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, bindingsource

Hej Folks,

Some background to the code: I have a WinForms project that is organized like the main form has only a menu and a panel and each menubutton loads in a separate form into this panel. This is working fine. I'm not sure if my problem has any relation with this setup but when I made a copy from the first form, no databindings are working on the new form. The form consists of a combobox and a datagridview. And while these are working fine with bindings on the original form, none of them are working on the new form. The initialisation is the same for each:

```
private readonly List<string> _listOfStrings = new List<string>();
private readonly BindingSource _gridBindingSource = new BindingSource();
private readonly List<Object> _listOfObjects = new List<Object>();
```

Binding for the combobox:

```
comboBoxSomeName.DataSource = new BindingSource(_listOfStrings, null);
```

Binding for the grid:

```
_gridBindingSource.DataSource = _listOfObjects;
dataGridViewItems.DataSource = _gridBindingSource;
```

Than I'm filling up the lists. I also tried to fill them up than bind, same result. It seems the lists are fine, the data is there and also the BindingSources can see them but not the controls. The controls itself are also fine, I can fill up the combobox with items.add and that can be seen. I'm really out of ideas what can be the problem, I appreciate all possible hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call _gridBindingSource.ResetBindings() after fill a list.

Comment: Gosh, you are right, I forgot that.. :) Generally the list had simular problem. I used a BackgoundWorker, and it finished to fill the list behind when it was already bound. Thanks.